# nvcc -Xptxas –v compiler flag has no effect

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have a CUDA project. It consists of several .cpp files that contain my application logic and one .cu file that contains multiple kernels plus a `__host__` function that invokes them.

Now I would like to determine the number of registers used by my kernel(s). My normal compiler call looks like this:

`nvcc -arch compute_20 -link src/kernel.cu obj/..obj obj/..obj .. -o bin/..exe -l glew32 ..`.

Adding the "-Xptxas –v" compiler flag to this call unfortunately has no effect. The compiler still produces the same textual output as before. The compiled .exe also works the same way as before with one exception: My framerate jumps to 1800fps, up from 80fps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not exactly what you were looking for, but you can use the CUDA visual profiler shipped with the nvidia gpu computing sdk. Besides many other useful informations, it shows the number of registers used by each kernel in you application.

Comment: this can't be correct because it does not answer the question... if you only wanted a way to count registers, then change the question.

Comment: @jimilloy "Now I would like to determine the number of registers used by my kernel(s)"

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, here is my solution:

1. Compile *cu files into device only *ptx file, this will discard host code

   `nvcc -ptx *.cu`
2. Compile *ptx file:

   `ptxas -v *.ptx`

The second step will show you number of used registers by kernel and amount of used shared memory.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the compute_20 to sm_20 in your compiler call. That should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When using "-Xptxas -v", "-arch" together, we can not get verbose information(register num, etc.).  If we want to see the verbose without losing the chance of assigning GPU architecture(-arch, -code) ahead, we can do the following steps:    `nvcc -arch compute_XX *.cu -keep`  then `ptxas -v *.ptx`. But we will obtain many processing files. Certainly, kogut's answer is to the point.

Answer (score 2):

when you *compile*

`nvcc --ptxas-options=-v`

Comment: doesn't work either. I've tried all various notations for that flag that can be found on the internet.

Comment: @Dav try removing link option and compile only

Comment: carp In this case the compiler complains about undefined external symbols.

Comment: @Dav break process in two, first compile, than link.

Comment: carp I tried nvcc -c ..cu -arch compute_20 --ptxas-options=-v - the compiler outputs a ..obj file but no register count

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ctrl your compiler verbose option defaults.

For example is VStudio goto :
Tools->Options->ProjectsAndSolutions->BuildAndRun
then set the verbosity output to Normal.